# Executing Visual Studio 2019, stored in a remote server

Tags: symbolic-link, remote-access, visual-studio, shared-folders

I have a personal computer, and a server. On both systems, Windows 10 Pro is already installed.

### TL;DR

I want to execute Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise on my personal computer, but place the application's installation location***s*** on the server.

### Full explanation

On my personal computer, I have a total of 32Gb of disk space. It goes without saying that the OS takes most of it, leaving behind at most 500Mb of free space. On the server, there's more than 500Gb of disk space. It's more than enough to install virtually any software that's currently publicly available.

My problem is that I can only execute Visual Studio 2019 (either community, pro, or enterprise) on my personal computer. I want to develop Android applications with Visual Studio, but the server doesn't have a recent enough processor to allow hardware acceleration, and in order to run an android emulator, I need this feature.

So, I'd like to know if it's possible to store the application on the server, but still be able to run it on my personal computer.

### What I tried so far

#### Attempt #1

I tried to create a shared folder on the server and replaced `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` with directory symbolic links (see [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1557e84f-591a-46bb-86c4-3b38af2003b0/can-i-replace-the-program-files-folder-with-a-symbolic-link-to-another-drive?forum=w7itprogeneral) post for how the idea came to me):

```
mklink /D "C:\Program Files" "\\server\windows\Program Files"
mklink /D "C:\Program Files (x86)" "\\server\windows\Program Files (x86)"
```

The problem is that permissions don't translate well over network directories. In other words, my personal computer can't execute anything that's stored through the symbolic link (at least, when I boot the OS and log into my account, a bunch of application-specific error messages are displayed (like "Microsoft Xbox Bar" not found, and many more)).

#### Attempt #1.1

I then tried to symlink Visual Studio's installation directories, as they are actually what I want to put remotely. The problem I encountered here is that I actually don't know where all of the Visual Studio "workloads" get installed. Apparently, it is not possible to customize many of Visual Studio's installation locations (see [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/change-installation-locations?view=vs-2019) for reference). Every software of a workload can have it's own installation location, and nothing seems customizable by the user.

#### Where I'm at

In the end, I succeeded to install Visual Studio 2019 on the server and run it on my computer. Only, I couldn't successfully install these workloads:

- `ASP.NET and web development`
- `Mobile development with .NET`
- `.NET Core cross-platform development`

And I can't write code / debug at all without them.

I'm about to buy a 1Tb external disk and install Visual Studio 2019 on it using the method described in *Attempt #1*. Do you have a better solution than this?

Comment: I too had the same problems (only not as bad).  I had 128gb SSD and 1tb HDD.  Visual Studio sucks for installation location options.  I also have Android Studio (which doubles up MUCH of the install).  Over a network is going to REALLY suck.  I myself installed to 'c' one piece at a time, moved the big stuff to 'd'.. then created junctions back to 'c'.  Programs are too stupid to know that they are using a junction.  I also do this with any other "big thing" that doesn't give me an option for where it goes.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas This must have been time consuming LOL. You might want to consider making symbolic links instead of junctions, and duplicate the permissions of the moved directories to the links (although maybe you encountered problems using symlinks?). Also, maybe a backup, just in case your SSD crashes or something. Anyways, in my case there are packages that simply cannot be installed (even individually) because of the low local storage capacity, so I would have to predict the installation directory of every component (and I don't know how to do that, I'm not a wizard).

Comment: I believe the only option in this situation is to move `C:\Program Files`, `C:\Program Files (x86)` and `C:\ProgramData` to the server. Those directories won't fit at all on the 32Gb disk when Visual Studio and Workloads get installed.

Answer (score 0):

I bought an ~80$ 1Tb external USB drive and installed Windows To Go on it using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). This solution solves the low disk space issue, and I don't need the server to be up and connected to my local network in order to boot on Windows.

I suggest you look at other answers if you don't want to waste your money like I did, though.

Comment: Although this solves my problem, I'm not marking as the accepted answer because it's definitely not solving the problem in the specific context described in the question (that is: machine 1 = *small* storage + processor *with* virtualization, machine 2 = *big* storage + processor *without* virtualization).

Comment: This is the correct solution.  Disk space is ridiculously cheap nowadays, and Visual Studio needs to stay on the computer's local hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get a 32GB (or other size) USB flash drive and store the shared `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` on the USB drive? That way you have space on the USB drive for VS 2019 components to be installed on the USB, and also enough space on the C: drive for the components that go in the `Program Data` folder. Or you can do the same thing with the `Program Data` folder as well.

Comment: In my case, I actually have linux installed on my computer, and I would have to resize and move the partitions of my system around to install Windows. In general, buying an external (or internal) drive of any size (32GB or more) to store `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)` and `Program Data`, and installing Windows on your computer's local storage (SSD if available) is probably the better setup. Windows To Go slows down your computer in order to run (using USB to transfer memory from disk to RAM has a huge overhead, and it's incredibly slow if the version used is USB 2.0).

Comment: I didn't say I use linux in the question because I thought it was an unnecessary detail, but I might edit if this question gets more attention later.